# ImportError: cannot import name 'pairwise_distances_chunked'

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, data-science, google-colaboratory

from imblearn.over_sampling import RandomOverSampler

while importing RandomOverSampler from imblearn.over_sampling in Google Colab  i am getting this error can any one help me to resolve this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suspect you need to restart your Python runtime before running the import statement. Use the Runtime -> Restart runtime menu.

[image]

The reason to restart is that I think you've imported the old version of `scikit-learn` prior to attempting to install and import `imblearn`. Presently, Colab bundles scikit-learn 0.19.2, but `imblearn` requires >= 0.20.

When you `!pip install imbalanced-learn`, that will update scikit-learn as needed. But, in order for your Python backend to pick up the change, you'll need to restart it if you've already imported the older bundled version.

Here's a complete example of installing and importing using a fresh backend:

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/137nStUAsbmeTBsTQ27G8rU9fwElTKp49